# django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers] got a redundant migration -> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "two_factor_phonedevice" already exists

Tags: python, django, totp, django-two-factor-auth

I'm facing the following database creation table error when spinning up a [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) project *from scratch* when I have [`django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth) in my requirements.

When I run the `migrate` command, it raises a `psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable` error:

```bash
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, projectapplication, otp_static, otp_totp, sessions, two_factor
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying projectapplication.0001_initial... OK
  (... project application migrations)
  Applying projectapplication.0032_alter_foo_bar_baz_and_more... OK
  Applying otp_static.0001_initial... OK
  Applying otp_static.0002_throttling... OK
  Applying otp_totp.0001_initial... OK
  Applying otp_totp.0002_auto_20190420_0723... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying two_factor.0001_initial... OK
  Applying two_factor.0002_auto_20150110_0810... OK
  Applying two_factor.0003_auto_20150817_1733... OK
  Applying two_factor.0004_auto_20160205_1827... OK
  Applying two_factor.0005_auto_20160224_0450... OK
  Applying two_factor.0006_phonedevice_key_default... OK
  Applying two_factor.0007_auto_20201201_1019... OK
  Applying two_factor.0008_delete_phonedevice... OK
  Applying two_factor.0009_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "two_factor_phonedevice" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 102, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "two_factor_phonedevice" already exists
```

This is the corresponding [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) log at that time:

```sql
2023-02-26 07:59:49.104 UTC [57] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-26 07:59:48 UTC
2023-02-26 07:59:49.110 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-02-26 08:00:58.733 UTC [72] ERROR:  relation "two_factor_phonedevice" already exists
2023-02-26 08:00:58.733 UTC [72] STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE "two_factor_phonedevice" (
        "id" bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
        "name" varchar(64) NOT NULL,
        "confirmed" boolean NOT NULL,
        "throttling_failure_timestamp" timestamp with time zone NULL,
        "throttling_failure_count" integer NOT NULL CHECK ("throttling_failure_count" >= 0),
        "number" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        "key" varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        "method" varchar(4) NOT NULL,
        "user_id" integer NOT NULL
    )
```

And if I check in the database, the table *already* exists as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.two_factor_phonedevice
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(64) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    confirmed boolean NOT NULL,
    "number" character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    key character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    method character varying(4) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    throttling_failure_count integer NOT NULL,
    throttling_failure_timestamp timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT two_factor_phonedevice_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT two_factor_phonedevice_user_id_54718003_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT two_factor_phonedevice_throttling_failure_count_check CHECK (throttling_failure_count >= 0)
);
```

Some more information about the migrations of the `two_factor` app:

```bash
$ ls -lA /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/two_factor/migrations/
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1851 Feb 25 21:55 0001_initial.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  597 Feb 25 21:55 0002_auto_20150110_0810.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1511 Feb 25 21:55 0003_auto_20150817_1733.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  454 Feb 25 21:55 0004_auto_20160205_1827.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1768 Feb 25 21:55 0005_auto_20160224_0450.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  608 Feb 25 21:55 0006_phonedevice_key_default.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  853 Feb 25 21:55 0007_auto_20201201_1019.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  380 Feb 25 21:55 0008_delete_phonedevice.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1992 Feb 26 08:59 0009_initial.py # <-------- this one is causing the trouble
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 25 21:55 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Feb 26 08:59 __pycache__
```

also:

```bash
$ python manage.py showmigrations two_factor
two_factor
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150110_0810
 [X] 0003_auto_20150817_1733
 [X] 0004_auto_20160205_1827
 [X] 0005_auto_20160224_0450
 [X] 0006_phonedevice_key_default
 [X] 0007_auto_20201201_1019
 [X] 0008_delete_phonedevice
 [ ] 0009_initial # <---- not run because of the above error
```

=> Here is the content of `0001_initial.py`:

```py
import django.core.validators
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PhoneDevice',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(help_text='The human-readable name of this device.', max_length=64)),
                ('confirmed', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Is this device ready for use?')),
                ('number', models.CharField(
                    max_length=16,
                    verbose_name='number',
                    validators=[django.core.validators.RegexValidator(
                        regex='^(\\+|00)',
                        message='Please enter a valid phone number, including your country code '
                                'starting with + or 00.',
                        code='invalid-phone-number'
                    )]
                )),
                ('key', models.CharField(help_text='Hex-encoded secret key', max_length=40)),
                ('method', models.CharField(
                    max_length=4,
                    verbose_name='method',
                    choices=[('call', 'Phone Call'), ('sms', 'Text Message')]
                )),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(
                    help_text='The user that this device belongs to.',
                    to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE
                )),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
    ]
```

=> And the content of `0009_initial.py`:

```py
# Generated by Django 4.1.7 on 2023-02-26 07:59

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django_otp.util
import phonenumber_field.modelfields
import two_factor.plugins.phonenumber.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('two_factor', '0008_delete_phonedevice'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PhoneDevice',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(help_text='The human-readable name of this device.', max_length=64)),
                ('confirmed', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Is this device ready for use?')),
                ('throttling_failure_timestamp', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=None, help_text='A timestamp of the last failed verification attempt. Null if last attempt succeeded.', null=True)),
                ('throttling_failure_count', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, help_text='Number of successive failed attempts.')),
                ('number', phonenumber_field.modelfields.PhoneNumberField(max_length=128, region=None)),
                ('key', models.CharField(default=django_otp.util.random_hex, help_text='Hex-encoded secret key', max_length=40, validators=[two_factor.plugins.phonenumber.models.key_validator])),
                ('method', models.CharField(choices=[('call', 'Phone Call'), ('sms', 'Text Message')], max_length=4, verbose_name='method')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(help_text='The user that this device belongs to.', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'two_factor_phonedevice',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Prior to the `two_factor` migrations, all other app migrations went well, in that order: `admin`, `auth`, `contenttypes`, `projectapplication`, `otp_static`, `otp_totp`, `session`.

I strictly followed the documentation for installing the two factor auth: https://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

which means that I added `django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]` to my `requirements.txt` + that I parametrized the `settings.py` with what is in the actual documentation.

`settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'project.apps.ProjectConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_bootstrap5',
    'import_export',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'two_factor',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    ...
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
]
```

I also added the `path(r'', include(two_factor.urls.urlpatterns)),` routes in the `urls.py`.

How can I identify what went wrong and what is needed to make my project run without errors?

---

##### Version info

- Python 3.9.13
- django 4.1.7
- django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers] in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (1.15.0)
- django-phonenumber-field<7,>=1.1.0 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (6.4.0)
- django-formtools in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (2.4)
- django-otp>=0.8.0 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (1.1.4)
- Django>=3.2 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (4.1.7)
- qrcode<7.99,>=4.0.0 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (7.4.2)
- phonenumbers<8.99,>=7.0.9 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (8.13.6)
- asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from Django>=3.2->django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (3.6.0)
- sqlparse>=0.2.2 in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from Django>=3.2->django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (0.4.3)
- typing-extensions in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from qrcode<7.99,>=4.0.0->django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (4.5.0)
- pypng in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` (from qrcode<7.99,>=4.0.0->django-two-factor-auth[phonenumbers]) (0.20220715.0)

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in the django-two-factor-auth dependency.

The Github discussion can be found here:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-two-factor-auth/issues/611

Proposed workaround from the Github thread:

```
python manage.py migrate phonenumber --fake-initial
```